# Broadcast socket

Tags: linux, networking

How I can see from shell what socket options are set? 
In particular I'm interesting to know if SO_BROADCAST is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you looked at [lsof](http://www.netadmintools.com/html/lsof.man.html)

Comment: Ok, indeed lsof has this capability - "- T f". But on my system (OpenSUSE 11.2 kernel 2.6.31) the option "f" to -T (selects reporting of socket options, states and values, and TCP flags and values.) is not available. This is indeed possible according to lsof man pages. So probably lsof is not a solution for me

Comment: Hmm, so probably Linux doesn't have an API for finding that out, otherwise lsof would know how to use it.